# UK visa vignette placed in expired passport by mistake. Can I still travel?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, passport-renewals

I applied for a UK standard visitor visa and was asked to present both my current and expired passports. When I received the decision, I realized that my visa vignette was placed in the expired passport! The visa in itself is correct.

I reported the error to the UKVI located in my country and haven't had a response.

Can I can travel with both passports?

Comment: What do you mean by the visa is correct? Are you sure all the details of the numbers and symbols typed on the visa, not only the dates but also the two rows of numbers at the bottom etc are related to the new passport and not the old?

Comment: could you please let me know what you did for your case? Did you try to travel with vignette on wrong passport or get it corrected with UKVI?

Answer (score 3):

Your visa has a machine readable bottom strip which contains the passport number (this image I have found in Google Images by searching for UK visa and I have only edited it to mark the passport number):

[image: passport with UK visa]

if this is your *expired* passport then all is well. I have traveled with a visa in my expired passport countless times (into the USA but that's immaterial) this is absolutely normal and accepted. If this is your *current* passport then you need to talk to the visa issuer immediately. This would be really bad because even in this case where you are absolutely not at fault you might find it challenging to just get a visa reissued for free. I would definitely not attempt travelling with a visa with the wrong passport number in it even if I hold the correct passport in my hand, as this would be unusual and god forbid to try to cross such hostile borders as the UK (or the USA) with an unusual case.